# Why use a stepper motor controller?

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor

Tutorials like [this one](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-10-stepper-motors/overview) recommend using a separate board in order to control a stepper motor. However, I don't really want to go and buy one (even though they are cheap).

My question is, why can't the stepper motor be controlled directly with a Raspberry Pi? If the problem is voltage or current, what stops me from just using a transistor?

Comment: there is nothing stopping you ... go ahead and use transistors

Comment: In all but perhaps the case of a low-curent unipolar motor run with darlingtons, there is in fact plenty of *practical* difficulty in the way of an inexperienced asker building a working driver with discrete transistors.  It can be done with care, but the more likely result is smoking quite a few parts first.  Especially for bipolar circuits and the FETs needed for low loss, doing the high side gate drive right, and without introducing a shoot-through risk means complexity beyond poking a few parts in a breadboard.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers like L293D and ULN2803 are just transistors in a box. there's no reason you couldn't cook up an equivalent from discrete parts.

8 `MMBTA14`, 8 resistors, and 8 diodes gets you a ULN2803 work-alike with more power, but the ULN2803 is cheaper and more compact.

If you want to get fancy with stepper motors - run several at the same time, di microstepping, or run several in tight synchronisation The problem is timing. stepper motors need precise timing for smooth operation.

a raspberry pi running Linux, or Windows mobile, or Risc-os, doesn't give guaranteed timing to user-space processes so, trying to run a stepper smoothly is not practical.

If you were to replace the OS with bare-bones code, then yeah it could do stepper motor tricks, but probably not do video or ethernet at the same time.

so to get fancy with stepper motos the best path is to use a stepper motor controller - this couldbe software running on an arduino, or a purpose bult board with drivers on it too.

Comment: The motor controllers in the tutorial in question are ULN2803 and L293.  These are "dumb" power stages.  They don't do their own timing; they rely on external timing.

Comment: oh, I thought they were actual stepper controllers

Comment: The L293 is also a horrible device best avoided.  There was some justification in the 1990's perhaps, but not today.  By the time you put one on the top and bottom of a bridge, those junction transistor losses really add up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the current. The raspberry pi's GPIO pins can only source or sink 20 mA, or is it 40 mA?

A stepper motor usually requires current in the range from 100 mA to 2000 mA, depending on torque and rotational speed. Read the datasheet for the stepper motor to see what it's actually rated for.

---

Another reason is that it's better to let a stepper motor controller take care of the micro-stepping and other time-important aspects, rather than letting the raspberry PI do it.